# Scheduling/path planning with constraint on start time for one node

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, schedule

I've been working on an itinerary-planning project and am having trouble coming up with an optimal scheduling/path-planning algorithm that works under certain constraints - namely that the path must stop at a particular node at a given time. I've constructed the problem statement as follows:

An itinerary has a start and end time (t<sub>s</sub> and t<sub>e</sub>), and is composed of activities {a<sub>1</sub>...a<sub>n</sub>}. Each activity a<sub>i</sub> has a start time t<sub>i</sub> and a duration d<sub>i</sub>. The first activity does not necessarily have to begin at t<sub>s</sub>.

Additionally, there is a cost of travel between each activity. I represent the cost of travel in an adjacency matrix C, where C[i][j] is the cost of traveling from a<sub>i</sub> to a<sub>j</sub>.

Here's where it gets tricky. There is one such activity a<sub>f</sub> ∈ {a<sub>1</sub>...a<sub>n</sub>} such that t<sub>f</sub> is fixed - the activity must begin at at time t<sub>f</sub>. At the same time, we want to minimize travel time as much as possible. I know there are algorithms to find the shortest Hamiltonian path, which I've already made use of to find the optimal order. The problem arises when the optimal order does not allow for the fixed activity to begin at its required time because it conflicts with the start/end times of the itinerary.

Is there an efficient algorithm to find the optimal order that still fulfills the constraint on activity a<sub>f</sub>?

The number of nodes will not exceed around 6 or 7. As such I'm not *overly* concerned with runtime growth, but still want to avoid brute-force searching if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that we can reach af before tf ,otherwise the solution may or may not exist depending on the input.

So I think this can be done by breaking the problem into two problems of minimizing the cost from (a1 to af) and (af to an).We will have the constrain to reach af before or at tf. We will always start the path from af to an at time tf+df as the time of af is fixed.So we now have to find the shortest path which can be found with the help of [Dijkstra Algorithm](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/dijkstra.html).